# Is it possible to concat for loop iteration value to $scope variable in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to concat for loop itteration value to scope variable in angular js?

```
$scope.rate1=220;
$scope.rate2=22123;
$scope.rate3=2223;
 ...
$scope.ratex=2223;

for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
{
alert($scope.rate.i);
alert($scope.rate[i]);
alert($scope.rate(i);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check working example : [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jpcB2LhtqCzTjAzLsuJq?p=preview)

Controller :

```
 $scope.rate1 = 220;
 $scope.rate2 = 22123;
 $scope.rate3 = 2223;

 for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
     alert($scope['rate' + i]);
 }
```

Comment: hi i am very new to this page, i dont know how to accept it

Comment: i got only 2 reputation. after getting 15 only.. it ll be possible